# MongoDb query to update the string array to object array

Tags: mongodb

Hi I am posting the question here first time. also I am new to mongodb. I have searched on the google but i did not find the answer. Currently in my collection i have list of string as

```
"keepOuts" : [
        "198,168,282,115,292,180", 
        "356,120,466,192,330,252,346,186"
    ]
```

I need a mongo db query which which will update all the documents in my collection such as

```
"keepOuts" : [
       {
           "coordinates" : "126,200,166,185,158,236", 
           "height" : NumberInt(0)
       }, 
       {
           "coordinates" : "146,141,169,107,192,154", 
           "height" : NumberInt(0)
       }
   ],
```

Here for each entry in old keepOuts each object is created and it will go in key coordinates also additional field is set into the the same object with key height. height will be by default 0.

I got the query from this portal it gives me the split array but it does not update the collection. query is

```
db.quoteDetails1.aggregate([
  {"$match":{keepOuts:{ $exists: true}}},
  {"$unwind": {path : "$keepOuts"}},
  {
    $group: {"_id": "$_id", 
    result:{
      $push:{
      coordinates:"$keepOuts"}}}}])
```

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
db.quoteDetails1.find({}).toArray().forEach(
function (elem) {
        for(var i = 0; i < elem.keepOuts.length; ++i) { 
            var obj = {"coordinates" : elem.keepOuts[i], "height": NumberInt(0)}
            elem.keepOuts[i] = obj
        }
        db.quoteDetails1.update({_id: elem._id}, elem);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer by below javascript

```
    db.getCollection('quoteDetails').find({keepOuts:{"$exists":true}}).forEach(
    function(doc) {    
      if(doc.keepOuts.length > 0){
        var array = doc.keepOuts;

        if(typeof array[0] === "string"){
            db.quoteDetails.update({"_id":doc._id},{"$set":{keepOuts :
            arrayToObj(doc)              
            }});
        }
      }
    }
);

function arrayToObj(doc){
    print("processing for" + doc._id);
    var array = doc.keepOuts;
    var len = array.length;
    var outerArray =[];

  for(var i = 0; i<len; i++){
    var obj = {};
    var curVal = array[i];
    obj["coordinates"]=curVal;
    obj["height"]=0; 
    outerArray.push(obj);
  }
  return outerArray;
}
```